# neo4j c# get all data

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4j-driver

I tried get all data from my neo4j database via neo4j driver (https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-dotnet-driver) and I have problem, because IResultCursor result have nodes only without edges. 
My code:

```
var records = new List<IRecord>();
IResultCursor result = await session.RunAsync("MATCH (n) RETURN n");
while(await result.FetchAsync())
{
      records.Add(result.Current);
}
```

After all list 'records' have nodes only. 
In the end I would like to ask you, how can I get query execution time? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a query that returns nodes and relationships

e.g. `MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) RETURN n,r,m`

for the execution time, you can either access the ResultSummary or just measure the time in your program.